# How to max out Will saves under level 4

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, saving-throw

Standard Paizo books.
20 point buy. 
150 starting gold.

How can one max out will saves at specifically level 1, but overall under level 4?

Classes, archetypes, feats, races, traits, and whatnot. If you want to talk about class features of future levels too or multi-classing could help as well.

(This is just a thought exercise so well-balanced characters would just be a bonus, not a requirement.)

Comment: This question is too broad, and off topic. It's too broad because there are a frankly staggering number of Pathfinder character build options that would have to be considered, and because you don't really define what "low-level" means here. It's off-topic because, by your own admission, you don't have a specific real problem to solve. SE works best when trying to solve a specific, real problem, and doesn't do so well with thought experiments like this.

Comment: I’ll slightly edit the question, but I agree with your overall sentiment.

Comment: For some advice on how to make good CharOp questions, look here: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-build-or-optimization-questions-on-topic

Comment: This question can possibly be steered closer to on track by explaining in the question *what prompted* this thought exercise.

Comment: What prompted it? I’m a nerd and think about random character creations during many waking hours. Hahah

Comment: @DuckTapeAl While SE in general sticks to the problem/resolution setup, I've seen numerous 'optimize for this' questions passed. Voted to reopen on the grounds of 'under level 4' being added.

Comment: @Ifusaso Optimization questions in general are fine, as the meta I linked says. The reason I think this question should be closed is that it's not optimization towards any purpose. Asking how to build a good character is fine. Asking how to maximize a specific stat, bereft of other context, is harder to make into a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting stat array gives +3

10-12-12-7-16-16

Aasimar race boosts it to +4

10-12-12-7-18-18

Take two levels of Paladin for Divine Grace. +3 base and +4 feature

Trait: Indomitable Will +1

Level 1 feat: Improved Willpower +2

Level multi-class into Cleric or something: +2

Looks like at level 3 without any magic items it will be:

Wisdom +4
Divine Grace +4
Trait +1
Feat +2
Paladin level 2 +3
Cleric level 1 +2

So a level 3 Character can easily have +16 to their will saves. The divine grace really helps out their other saves too. That being said, at level 1 the Will save will still be a respectable +9.

Special shout out to the Protection Cleric Domain for its +1 Resistance Bonus... that would make the Will +10 at level 1.

I’m sure there might be some archetypes and alternate class features I’m missing, plus the obvious eventual Cloak of Resistance, or the Greater Improved Will feat, but this character would be very hard to mind control!

(One could also completely dump the other 4 stats to bump the starting aasimar array to 8-7-7-7-20-20. That would give an extra +1 from WIS and another +1 from Divine Grace. Which would be silly.)

Comment: The question asked for the highest Will save **at level 1**. Taking 2 levels of paladin plus a multiclass is not an option.